# Related to JMS Listener

Tags: java

Currently I am facing issues with related to JMS Listener. JMS listener is not actively picking all the messages, instead randomly selects the input messages and process it. Because of this, for few messages I could see user details being displayed, for others its not. There is inconsistency in displaying results. It is difficult to trace where the listener is actively running in the background because in my colleague's local machine, I could see listener picking messages randomly and processing it.(he does not have my code changes and so user details are not displayed). Have anyone faced this scenario? Is there any solution? I tried to push the same message (which does not show user details) from my local workspace and it is executed fine. This is to ensure my code is right or not.

Comment: It is very hard to give you any good feedback based on the information given. The only time I can recall something similar happening is when we had multiple servers (or multiple environments) connected to the same queue so some messages were sent to one server/environment and the others to another server/environment, giving the illusion of messages being lost or unprocessed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.